# XCode archive codesign

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, archive, codesign

I used XCode to Archive my signed app. No issue regarding build, sandbox, certificat, ...

You can see bellow the details of the signed app :

```
iMac-de-Admin:~ admin$ codesign -dvvv /Users/admin/Downloads/Alphonso.app 
Executable=/Users/admin/Downloads/Alphonso.app/Contents/MacOS/Alphonso
Identifier=com.Alphonso-soft.Alphonso
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=2995 flags=0x0(none) hashes=141+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=82820d57a3c4b9d945177df5983eed3eb84e9580
Signature size=4340
Authority=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: John Doe
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=8 févr. 2013 17:07:53
Info.plist entries=20
Sealed Resources rules=4 files=77
Internal requirements count=1 size=196
iMac-de-Admin:~ admin$
```

The app seems to be signed correctly but when i run the app i get the following Warning/Error :

```
“Alphonso” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
```

Is it normal ?

Thanks

Comment: "Is it normal?" - Certainly not. The **normal** behavior would be if you could just darn install your **own** app on your **own** device without paying to Apple, adding extraneous code signing, and all those brainless and painful restrictions that Apple imposes on developers. Nuff said.

Comment: I've reinstalled Mountain Lion on my mac. No XCode, No certificat installed yet. In this case is it normal ?

Comment: @H2CO3 If it isn't painful it isn't security.

Comment: @Zaph How'bout Linux...

Comment: Will try to change certificate. The "3rd Party ..." certificates are for submitting to the App Store.  Will try "Developer ID ..." certificates for that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Linux, like in secure Android? Apple made a decision to have age ratings and that alone demands no side-loading and curation. There is "jailbreaking" available for those who are willing to weaken security.

Comment: @Zaph 1. Android != Linux. Google made quite a mess of it. 2. Only if there was Gatekeeper on iOS or another official way of liberating the device... What if jailbreaking becomes impossible one day? It's getting harder and harder...

Comment: @H2CO3 If iOS becomes completely secure those wanting a less secure system can go elsewhere. That is if iOS does not meet their needs there are other alternatives. Allowing side-loading does not allow parental control, Apple chose that route and there is baggage that goes along with it. iOS does not meet the need of everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "3rd Party ..." certificates are for submitting to the App Store.

Use "Developer ID ..." certificates solve the issue.

Enter the following command in Terminal by replacing TrackMix.app with the path to your application.

```
$ sudo spctl -a -v TrackMix.app
```

If the application is correctly signed, text similar to the following appears in Terminal:

```
./TrackMix.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
```